# Как написать Adapter для ListView

Tags: android, mysql, listview, adapter

Здравствуйте! Есть код для вывода (из бд mysql) списка имен по выбранному отделу (название отдела экспортируется с другой activity). Выводится просто в ListView. Как написать и применить adapter, чтобы каждая строка выводилась в виде модели?

```
public class ShowDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String FinalHttpData = "";
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
    WebCallParse webCallParse = new WebCallParse();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    OutputStream outputStream ;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String Result ;
    ListView SubjectListView;
    String HttpURL = "http://10.204.1.88/Android/people.php";
    String ParseResult ;
    HashMap<String,String> ResultHash = new HashMap<>();
    URL url;
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter ;
    String FinalJSonObject ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_details);

        SubjectListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        String TempItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("Otdel");

        HttpWebCall(TempItem);

    }


    public void HttpWebCall(final String PreviousListViewClickedItem){

        class HttpWebCallFunction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

                FinalJSonObject = httpResponseMsg ;

                new GetHttpResponse(ShowDetailsActivity.this).execute();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                ResultHash.put("Query",params[0]);

                ParseResult = webCallParse.postRequest(ResultHash);

                return ParseResult;
            }
        }

        HttpWebCallFunction httpWebCallFunction = new HttpWebCallFunction();

        httpWebCallFunction.execute(PreviousListViewClickedItem);
    }

    public class WebCallParse {

        public String postRequest(HashMap<String, String> Data) {

            try {
                url = new URL(HttpURL);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(12000);

                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.write(FinalDataParse(Data));

                bufferedWriter.flush();

                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                            )
                    );
                    FinalHttpData = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                else {
                    FinalHttpData = "Something Went Wrong";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return FinalHttpData;
        }

        public String FinalDataParse(HashMap<String, String> hashMap2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            for(Map.Entry<String, String> map_entry : hashMap2.entrySet()){

                stringBuilder.append("&");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilder.append("=");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

            }

            Result = stringBuilder.toString();

            return Result ;
        }
    }

    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                if(FinalJSonObject != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonObject);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            listString.add(jsonObject.getString("name").toString()) ;

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ShowDetailsActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, listString);

            SubjectListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
    }

}
```

Модель, например, такая

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: это не модель, а разметка айтема списка. Модель это единица данных, представленная объектом, обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю здесь лучше посмотреть в сторону RecyclerView. Вы сможете так создать для каждого элемента свою модель и добавить функции, удаления, поиска, редактирование и т.д.

Вот не большой пример, можете свои данные подставить и модель поменять. Думаю поймете принцип

```
public class Adapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context mcontext;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
public ArrayList<History> filterList;
public ArrayList<History> mHistory;
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
LocataionHistory locataionHistory;
CustomFilter filter;


public Adapter(ArrayList<History> list, Context context, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, LocataionHistory locataionHistory) {

    this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
    this.locataionHistory = locataionHistory;
    mHistory = locataionHistory.getHistoryList();
    filterList = locataionHistory.getHistoryList();
    mcontext = context;
}

// Called when RecyclerView needs a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder of the given type to represent an item.
@Override
public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                             int viewType) {
    // create a layout
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.list, null);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position ) {

    viewHolder.name.setText(mHistory.get(position).getLanguage());
    viewHolder.perevod.setText(mHistory.get(position).getLanguage_perevod());
    viewHolder.cod.setText(mHistory.get(position).getLanguage_cod());

    if(mHistory.get(position).getIsIzbrannoe() == true)
    {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
    }


    viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mHistory.get(position).getIsIzbrannoe() == true)
            {
                viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                locataionHistory.nastroika(mHistory.get(position), false);
                mHistory.get(position).setIzbrannoe(false);

            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
                locataionHistory.nastroika(mHistory.get(position), true);
                mHistory.get(position).setIzbrannoe(true);

            }

          //  locataionHistory.nastroika(mHistory.get(position));
        }
    });

}

//Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHistory.size();
}

// initializes some private fields to be used by RecyclerView.
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView perevod;
    public TextView cod;
    public ImageView imageView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        perevod = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.perevod);
        cod = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.cod);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageTest);

    }
    }
}
}
```

А вот пример использования

```
public class Fragment_history extends Fragment  {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

Adapter mAdapter;


ArrayList<History> historyList;
LocataionHistory locataionHistory;
SearchView sv;
static final String TAG = "myLogs";

public static Fragment_history newInstance() {
    return new Fragment_history();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


    locataionHistory = (LocataionHistory) getActivity().getApplication();
    historyList = locataionHistory.getHistoryList();



    // call the adapter with argument list of items and context.


        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mAdapter = new Adapter(historyList, getActivity(), getActivity(), locataionHistory);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    sv= (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.mSearch);

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            //FILTER AS YOU TYPE
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

А так же лаяуты для них

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:id="@+id/imageTest"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/perevod"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cod"
        android:layout_above="@+id/perevod"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="qqqq"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageTest"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageTest" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/perevod"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

А тут для RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/mSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:defaultQueryHint="Найти в истории"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/border"/>
```